# InputStream to Hadoop SequenceFile

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a generic input stream that represents a sequence file. I would like to create a SequenceFile.Reader, or a similar class, from it with out needing to write the output stream to a temp file on disk. Is there something that would like me go from an input stream to something that would allow me to read the key/value pairs from the inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, there doesn't appear to be any documentation on the current SequenceFile.Reader class, but looking through the code for Hadoop 2.0+, I believe the following would work:

```
FSDataInputStream inputStream = new FSDataInputStream (rawInputStream);
Option isOption = SequenceFile.Reader.stream(inputStream);
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(hadoopConf,isOption);
```

You may also be interested in the options `start` and `length`, where `start` is how many bytes to skip before reading the sequence file, and `length` is how many bytes to read from the stream. Setting up that reader might look like this:

```
FSDataInputStream inputStream = new FSDataInputStream (rawInputStream);
Option isOption = SequenceFile.Reader.stream(inputStream);
Option lengthOption = SequenceFile.Reader.length(100000);
Option startOption = SequenceFile.Reader.start(10);
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(hadoopConf,isOption,lengthOption,startOption);
```

Finally, once you have constructed your `Reader`, you can read through your values as such:

```
Text key = new Text();
Text val = new Text();
while (reader.next(key,val)) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Again, I have not tested this code at all, but this *should* work in theory. If you are not using Hadoop 2.0+, I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: I do not see a Reader.stream or a Reader constructor that matches those formats. Guessing that is what you meant by Hadoop 2.x not being documented. But that is what I want to accomplish, just doesn't work in 2.x

Comment: The code is there, it is just not documented. Have you tried just compiling this code?

Comment: Yup, undefined method Reader.stream

Comment: Ok. So that means you are not using Hadoop 2.x. What version are you using?

Comment: Crap, I forgot that it takes an FSDataInputStream, and not a raw. I've updated my answer to reflect this...

Comment: I must not have a new enough hadoop core as the methods do not exist in the attached source code. Also your FSDataInputStream(rawStream) the rawStream has to implement Seekable and PositionReadable. Thank you for the help btw

Comment: That is true. If your rawStream does not, then what you are trying to do will simply never work. Seekable is a big part of how sequence files are read.